# Detecting SyntaxError when fetching data via JSONP

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jsonp, syntax-error

I'm trying to detect a `SyntaxError` when accessing potentially malformed resources via JSONP using jQuery.

When I execute something like this

```
try
{
  $.ajax("http://www.google.com", {dataType:"jsonp"});
  alert("good");
}
catch(e)
{
 alert("bad");
}
```

I get the `"good"` message together with an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` coming from `www.google.com:1`. What I'd like to get is the `"bad"` message. I'm using Chrome but I'd like a cross-browser solution if possible.

Is there a way to suppress the `SyntaxError` and detect that the returned resource is not a valid JSONP document?

Answer (score 0):

[`window.onerror`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onerror) catches all JavaScript syntax errors. You might use it like so:

```
$.ajax("http://www.google.com", {dataType:"jsonp"});

window.onerror = function(msg, url, linenumber) {
    if((msg == "Script error." || msg == "Syntax error") &&
        url.indexOf("http://www.google.com/") == 0) {

        alert("bad");

    }
}
```